# disable the button till the input fields are filled not working

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable the submit button till all the input fields are filled in the page using angularjs/bootstrap. I tried using `ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"` but it doesn't seem to work. Any inputs?

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mqIYIx4KIlOV1JOSHVJI?p=preview)

**HTML Code**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <div>Select Color : </div>
      <label name="team" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)" required> {{color}}
                  <br>  </label><br>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.color.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.color.$error.required">Please Select the color</p>
                </div>
            <div class="">
                <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
               <input type="text" name="user" value="" required>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you have checked wrong condition in controller function :  $scope.submitForm = function(){ }

Comment: try ------  if (($scope.selectedColor == "" || $scope.selectedColor == undefined) && ($scope.user == "" || $scope.user == undefined)) { //invalid } else { //valid}

Comment: I want to disable the submit button until inputs fields are filled, I.e, at least one checkbox should be checked and text should be entered in text box to enable the submit button do that user can submit the form.

Comment: Hmm I tried that way , if possible can you edit my plunker, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed to add ng-model for checkbox and textbox.

Can you please check below code.

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-checkbox-input-directive-production</title>
   <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body ng-app="checkboxExample">
  <script>  
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      
      $scope.colorNames = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'BLACK'];
        $scope.selectedColor = [];
        $scope.userSelection = function userSelection(team) {
            var idx = $scope.selectedColor.indexOf(team);
           if (idx > -1) {
                $scope.selectedColor.splice(idx, 1);
            }
            else {
                $scope.selectedColor.push(team);
            }
        };
        $scope.submitForm = function(){
             if ($scope.selectedColor != "" && $scope.selectedColor != undefined && $scope.user != "" && $scope.user != undefined) {
          alert("all fields are entered");
            }else{
               
            }
        } 
        
    
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <div>Select Color : </div>
      <label name="team" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="color" ng-model="colouer" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)" required> {{color}}
                  <br>  </label><br>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.color.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.color.$error.required">Please Select the color</p>
                </div>
            <div class="">
                <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
               <input type="text" name="user" value="" ng-model="username" required>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

   

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written the condition wrong. Please write ng-disabled="!myForm.$invalid". Also, writing {{myForm.$invalid}} in html shows its current value which was false in your case.

```
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
       <div>Select Color : </div>
          <label name="team" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)" required> {{color}}
                      <br>  </label><br>
                    <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.color.$touched">
                        <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.color.$error.required">Please Select the color</p>
                    </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
                   <input type="text" name="user" value="" required>
                    <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                        <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
{{myForm.$invalid}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)" ng-disabled="!myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `ng-model` to your input field

```
  <input type="text" name="user" value="" ng-model="user" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 additional things,
  1. Use ng-required for all the inputs instead of required. and add ng-model 
     for all the inputs. 
  2. for checkboxes, you need to check if atleast one of the checkboxes is 
     selected. If one is selected you can make ng-required = false. 
     For that you can check if the length of the selectedColor is greater 
     than 0.

PFB the modified code,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-checkbox-input-directive-production</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="checkboxExample">
  <script>  
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.colorNames = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'BLACK'];
        $scope.selectedColor = [];
        $scope.userSelection = function userSelection(team) {
            var idx = $scope.selectedColor.indexOf(team);
          if (idx > -1) {
                $scope.selectedColor.splice(idx, 1);
            }
            else {
                $scope.selectedColor.push(team);
            }
        };
        $scope.submitForm = function(){
            if ($scope.selectedColor != "" && $scope.selectedColor != undefined && $scope.user != "" && $scope.user != undefined) {
          alert("all fields are entered");
            }else{

            }
        } 


    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div>Select Color : </div>
      <label name="team" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" name="color" ng-required="selectedColor.length==0" value="{{color}}" ng-click="userSelection(color)" > {{color}}
                  <br>  </label><br>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.color.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.color.$error.required">Please Select the color</p>
                </div>
            <div class="">
                <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
              <input type="text" name="user" value="" ng-model="user" ng-required="true">
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did two changes:

1. add ng-model for your fields
2. in check boxes I change the model name as `ng-model="color_$index"`

**$index** get the index of the array and it helps to identify each checkbox individually.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <div>Select Color : </div>
                <label name="team" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="color" ng-model="color_$index" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)" required> {{color}}
                    <br>
                </label>
                <br>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.color.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.color.$error.required">Please Select the color</p>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
                    <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="username" value="" required>
                    <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                        <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
        </form>
```